# Why is my view controller black when pushing from tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to push to a view controller from my tab bar controller. Keep in mind that none of this done on a storyboard -- it is strictly programmatic. Every time I push to the controller the navigation bar shows up with the back button, but the view is completely black:

```
let controller = NewsFeedDetailViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

I am not quite sure why it is coming up this way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

When `pushViewController` programmatically, if you didn't set destination controller's `backgroundColor`, by default it's black(no background color). Try to give a color like so:

```
class NewsFeedDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg I feel really stupid. Sorry for wasting your time. Thank you :(

Comment: @butter_baby No problem. It's a learning process. I used to make the same mistake . Happy coding :)